# Can't boot to Windows 8 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

First of all, I know a lot of people has asked this question, but after revising a lot of questions, I didn't find my answer so I ask here because I'm desesperated and I need a solution... Here's my problem:

I have Windows 8.1 preinstalled in my PC, and I've also installed Ubuntu 12.04. Firstly, when I installed it, it worked perfectly and I didn't have any problem running the two OS.
But, lately, this last week, it gave me some errors because I couldn't start Ubuntu, so I reinstalled it. The problem now is that when I try to access my Windows 8.1, it gives me this error:

> Error: no boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed.

When I enter my BIOS settings, it successfully shows the Windows Boot Manager under the boot menu options, but when I try to access it, it gives me that error. Also, I've tried to solve the problem with the Windows 8 recovery mode but it doesn't detect my OS...
I know my hard drive is working, because I can access to my Ubuntu and I can also access my Windows 8 files through Ubuntu.

I've found **[this guide](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-in-windows-8/#.UySFzdsYbx9)** but I'm not sure if it's what I have to do, is it?
If this could solve my problem, I'm stucked in the first step where I have to assign my EFI partition a drive letter, because I don't know which volume is my EFI partition.

So, I would appreciate it a lot if you could help me because I really need to access my Windows 8.1 without losing any data...
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the "startup repair" option in the Win8 recovery? Most likely only Windows 8 will show up after that, so I would use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to add Linux to the list afterwards. Also please clarify what you actually want to do in your question. Do you want to have a running Windows installation? Linux only? Impossible for us to know, having "access to your Windows 8.1" isn't clear, do you want to boot it or salvage data from it? Also see http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html

Comment: @bigbadonk420 Oh, sorry for not being clare. What I want is to have accessible my Windows 8 via the Ubuntu GRUB menu, like it has been always working. Btw, two or three months ago, I tried to use easyBCD but I couldn't access Ubuntu via that menu. Now my problem is that I can't access Windows 8, so I want to repair the Windows boot menu so it lets me access either my Ubuntu or my Windows.

Comment: So did you try "Startup repair" or not? That should give you a working Win8 boot menu, and adding Ubuntu from there should be trivial with EasyBCD. Your other option is booting Ubuntu from USB and reinstalling GRUB if you want to use that: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.UySWiR9CUVk -- for dual boot I usually prefer just modding the Windows boot screen

Comment: @bigbadonk420 Yes, I tried startup repair, the automatic one. But when I try it, it asks me for a OS to boot from, but I have no systems in that list. Also, my Ubuntu is recently installed, because I reinstalled it one or two days ago. The problem is for my Windows... When I try to boot to it, it gives me the error: boot disk not detected or the disk has failed.

Comment: So you're actually getting a GRUB screen just fine, but choosing the Windows option there gives you the error message?

Comment: @bigbadonk420 No exactly, that's the message I get from booting directly from the Windows boot manager. But when I boot through GRUB (and yes, GRUB screen is just fine!) I get this error: http://pastebin.com/jw3jwd1f

Comment: see ankeets answer below and comment there if you have further issues

Comment: The "no boot disk" error you report in the main question is a Windows boot error, and so will have a Windows solution. Overall, I don't think this is an Ubuntu or GRUB problem; it's a Windows problem. Oh, and "access" is a vague verb as you've been using it. If you mean "boot," write "boot." If you mean "mount," write "mount," etc.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 Okay, thanks for all the help!!

Comment: @RodSmith Sorry, I'm not english-speaker so I try to do my best when I speak english... Thanks for the feedback, I'll try to use that! :D

Answer (score 2):

Follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)`Ubuntu community page for your problem. It can surely helps you in a long way.And if any problems occurs after these steps please comment below .

Comment: Oh, thanks! So with this I can assume that Windows is installed in EFI mode and I'll have to reinstall Ubuntu in EFI mode too, am I right?

Comment: Does you run  the [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) as mentioned in community wiki,As far as my experience says you don't have to reinstall the Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, I've done what the guide (the one I put in the main post) said, and now I can boot into Windows. But the problem now is that the Windows 8 option in the GRUB menu doesn't work. So, do I have to use now the Ubuntu boot-repair to change that setting in GRUB, like you said?

Comment: Yes , try the boot-repair and click on recommend setup. After the repair it generates a log file and a customized detail URL , save it, if in-case any problem occurs. This can surely helps you.As you previously mentioned you can also check whether secure boot option is turned off or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look via Gparted how big your EFI-partition is and then identify it simply by the size.

Comment: Oh, thanks for answering! [Here is a screenshot of my GParted](http://screencloud.net/v/ewP8), where I can see that the efi partition is the one with 360MB, so it should be the Volume 6 partition, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

When your system boots up hit f12 repeatedly a few times to get an os selection menu. Select windows 8 boot manager there and hit return key. Your windows 8 os should start normally. Worked for me.